# How to post laravel form data to controller using ajax in API

Tags: php, laravel, android-webview, postman

I have a form, which is opened in the Android web view, I want to save data to the database, but when I have making an ajax call and try to print data is showing a blank array, following are my code :

```
<div class="card-body card-padding">
    <form id="submitdataform">
        @csrf
        @foreach($formfields as $key=>$value)
            <input type="hidden" name="campaign_id" value="{{$key}}"/>
            @foreach($value as $attrkey)
                <input type="hidden" name="attribute_id[]" value="{{$attrkey->id}}"/>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="pure-material-textfield-outlined w-100">
                                {{--<input placeholder=" " type="text" required>--}}
                                <?php
                                if ($attrkey->attribute_type == 'alpha') {
                                    echo "<input placeholder=' ' type='text' name='attribute_value[]' required>";
                                } elseif ($attrkey->attribute_type == 'date') {
                                    echo "<input placeholder=' ' type='date' name='attribute_value[]' required>";
                                } elseif ($attrkey->attribute_type == 'numberic') {
                                    echo "<input placeholder=' ' type='number' name='attribute_value[]' required>";
                                }
                                ?>
                                <span>{{$attrkey->attribute_name}}</span>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            @endforeach
        @endforeach
        <button type="button" id="submitbtn">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Now ajax call

```
$("#submitbtn").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var data = $("#submitdataform").serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "savecampaigndata",
        data: {data: data},
        contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            // Android.passParams('dashboard');
        },
        error: function (data) {
            // Android.passParams(url);
        }
    });
});
```

And this is the controller method where I want to get all my data ,

```
public function SaveCampaignData(Request $request)
{
    return response()->json($request->all());
    $data = $request->all();
    $attribute_id = [];
    $attribute_value = [];
    $campaign_id = $data['campaign_id'];
    $user_id = Auth::user()->id;

    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        if ($key == "attribute_id") {
            foreach ($value as $attrkey) {
                $attribute_id[] = $attrkey;
            }
        } else {
            if ($key == "attribute_value") {
                foreach ($value as $attrvalue) {
                    $attribute_value[] = $attrvalue;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    $mainArray = array_combine($attribute_id, $attribute_value);
    $currentdate = Carbon::now();
    foreach ($mainArray as $key => $value) {
        DB::table('campaign_attribute_values')->insert(
            [
                'campaign_id'              => $campaign_id,
                'campaign_attribute_id'    => $key,
                'user_id'                  => $user_id,
                'campaign_attribute_value' => $value,
                'created_at'               => $currentdate,
                'updated_at'               => $currentdate,
            ]
        );
    }

    if ($this->CheckSmsLimit() > 0) {
        $this->checkAutoReply($campaign_id, $user_id);
    }

    return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Request Registered');
//        return response()->json(['status' => true, 'message' => 'Record saved succesfully', 'code' => 200]);
}
```

This is postman route URL :

```
https://subdomain.xyz.com/savecampaigndata
```

But it's giving a blank array as output in my controller.

Comment: Seems that you forgot to add the _token field in the form, for csrf, or just add this route to the exceptions, but that is bad practice

Comment: @csrf is already added and also ajax setup in my app file

Comment: remove  contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', from ajax request

Comment: I have already tried all these thing's , but unable to send data to controller

Comment: One important things this view file is opening in **android webview **

Comment: try a console log on the success and error function of the response, see what it gives you, look at the http status code. Is it 500? Is it 404? Is it 302? Is it 200?

Comment: Sir@lessan I am calling this url by postman

Comment: Can you try to call the url like : url: "/savecampaigndata",

Comment: yes I also tried this

Comment: Please can you show the data for `$formfields`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$("#submitbtn").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var data = $("#submitdataform").serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "{{ url('savecampaigndata) }}",
        data: {data: data},
        success: function (data) {
            // Android.passParams('dashboard');
        },
        error: function (data) {
            // Android.passParams(url);
        }
    });
});
```

1. if you don't want to send csrf token

then

```php
app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php
```

and add this route's url to the except array

```php
protected $except = [
   'savecampaigndata'
];
```

2. if want

then add in head

```html
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

and in script

```js
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add '/' in url attribute of ajax call & add header attribute also in ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the reason you're getting a blank response is because of `csrf`. I see that you have included it in your form, however, because you're using `serialize` it won't work the way you expect it to.

The are a few different ways you can add the csrf:

1. If your script is inside your blade file you could simply add it to the data object:

   ```
   data: {
       data: data,
       _token: "{{ csrf_token() }}",
   },
   ```

   **Or**
2. as per the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/csrf#csrf-x-xsrf-token) you could add the following inside the `<head>` of your page :

   ```
   <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
   ```

   and then included the following after you've pulled in jQuery:

   ```
   $.ajaxSetup({
       headers: {
           'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
       }
   });
   ```